# Is the dated meaning of brick as a good, reliable person ever used outside the expression "to be a brick"?

Tags: word-usage, obscure-terms

I first came across the expression *to be a brick* in the spoof of Enid Blyton's Famous Five series - *The Comic Strip Presents: Five Go Mad in Dorset*. A few times one of the characters says to another [*You really are a brick!*](https://youtu.be/gsyEQk6OQi0?t=445) (YouTube link)

A few online dictionaries' definitions:

- Cambridge: [brick](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brick)
- The Free Dictionary: [brick](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/brick)
- Wiktionary: [brick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brick)
- Oxford Learner's Dictionaries: [brick](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/brick_1)

Can this meaning of *brick* be used outside the phrase(s) *to be a brick* / *to be a real brick* / *to really be a brick*? Or perhaps outside of a copulative expression such as *You're becoming a real brick!*?

None of the dictionaries list *to be a brick* as an idiom. They all have a separate meaning for *brick*. Hence, if it can't be used in any other phrase, why not?

Comment: Please don't say "You're becoming a real brick!" the phrase is "You are a brick". But old-fashioned as you say: some might think of "a brick in the wall" which is quite different.

Comment: @WeatherVane The existence of one phrase does not negate the possibility of the existence of others. That's why I asked my question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I answered your question. "You're becoming a real brick!" could be easily misconstrued. Apart from anything else, it implies that they aren't yet, so it is no longer a compliment.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't see why it couldn't be used like that. E.g. to a young child who is learning to be helpful as encouragement to continue improving.

Comment: Because mis-using idioms will always get you into trouble, or looked at strangely. For example "Have you taken the biscuit?" isn't likely to be understood, because it is only *related to* the idiom "that takes the biscuit!"

Comment: @WeatherVane - Note that "you're a real brick" is an existing idiom, it's not always just "you're a brick". Given that this usage of "brick" means a friend one can rely on, in the right context "you're becoming a real brick" could be taken to mean "you're becoming a good friend" - that usage sounds fine to me, but sounds wrong if the word "real" is omitted.